# Displaying the number from the sequence by using the sequence ID

Tags: c++, sequence

Let's say there is a sequence of 4 numbers. All of these numbers repeat themselves every fourth time. The numbers are, in correct order: 2, 4, 8, 6. So for example:
ID 1: 2
ID 2: 4
ID 3: 8
ID 4: 6
ID 5: 2
ID 6: 4
ID 7: 8
And so on.
My question is, can i calculate and display one of the numbers that corresponds to that sequence ID (2, 4, 8 or 6) by only receiving the sequence ID as the input.
I just need the mathematical equation for finding it, but i'll be equally happy if someone would give me this equation as a ideally, C++ script.
Ill be happy for any answer. Thanks.

I tried to find a way to find the number using the remainder from the division of the ID entered by the user by 10, so for example:
`if(IDint % 10 == 1) cout << 2;`
But I quickly realised that not every ID ending by 1 will have the number 2, so I'm kind of lost at this point.
Thanks again.

Comment: the example is unclear. What is the "sequence ID" you get as input and what is "one of the numbers" you need to produce as output?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. SO is not a code writing service. Asking to provide code for you is offtopic. If you tried something, include a [mcve] of your code in the question. If you didnt try something, this is a question about `algorithm` not about `c++`

Comment: are you looking for `if((IDint-1) % 4 == 0) cout << 2;` ?!?

Comment: You have an endless repetition of a cycle of size 4. a "sequence ID" is therefore of the form `4*k+i`. You can recover `i` by taking the sequence ID modulo 4. This is `sequence_id % 4` as the previous comment stated. You can recover the final number by simply indexing into the array `[2,4,8,6]` by `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track using the remainder operator `%` (modulo), however you used the wrong divisor. A divisor of 10 will repeat a sequence of 10 numbers, whereas what you need is 4 numbers. So the divisor should be 4 in your case.

That's half of the equation. Then, it's a simple transformation to go from the 1-based sequence ID to a 0-based system for the modulo operation. To do that you simply subtract 1 from your sequence ID first. And if you're more comfortable dealing with 1-based values after wrapping, then you can add 1 again.

So your math should have been:

```
int seq_id = 1 + (IDint - 1) % 4;
if (seq_id == 1) cout << 2;
if (seq_id == 2) cout << 4;
if (seq_id == 3) cout << 8;
if (seq_id == 4) cout << 6;
```

This is a lot of repeated code though. It would be cleaner to store your sequence in an array or vector, and then calculate a (zero-based) index for it.

Here's an example of selecting values from any repeating non-zero length sequence starting from a 1-based ID:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> seq{ 2, 4, 8, 6 };
    for (int id = 1; id < 42; id++)
    {
        int selected = seq[(id-1) % seq.size()];
        std::cout << selected << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 4 8 6 2 4 8 6 2 4 8 6 2 4 8 6 2 4 8 6 2 4 8 6 2 4 8 6 2 4 8 6 2 4 8 6 2 4 8 6 2
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but i have one more question. Why do i have to subtract 1 before doing the modulo operation? Thanks.

Comment: My second paragraph says why. Your IDs are 1-based. If you don't subtract 1, then the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 will become 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0. That's not what you wanted. Something you could actually do instead of asking me is to ask yourself: _"what happens if I don't subtract 1?"_ and then actually test that. Then you would see what the difference is. I only used 1-based IDs here because you do. I wouldn't normally do that. In C++, 0-based systems are more natural.